# Python Bitboard more than 64bit using Numpy lib

Tags: python, numpy, bitboard

i'm actually trying to create an AI that can play a board game.
My problem is that the boardgame is using a 9x9 square, so i can't use a 64bitboards like usually. Is there any way on how to use more than 64bitboard?

I though of using 3 32bit integer, but i can't really see on how to do so

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm sorry, i really have forgotten to say that i should use numpy lib, which support only to 64bits integer